# Drupal 7 - Display single image from multiple image field in View

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to display just single image from field with multiple upload option enabled in my View. The best would be to display the first uploaded image, but It does not matter.

I have tried to add that galerry field to field, and was looking for some settings that will give me that option to show only specific or some images.

Is it possible in View to display single image from gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From views if you are using views to display you content 
There is settings for multiple valued field you can display specific number items or single item 
Just click on that field you will find this setting

[image]

If you need to control this from your node display 
[Single Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_image_formatter) this module helps you 
Thanks